# In App issue in Amazon Kindle Fire

Tags: android, amazon-s3, in-app-purchase

i am trying to develope in app for amazon in android. at this time i download a code from amazon sample code and this i,plement this in my app. On running app on Kindle Fire i recived these responses:

but after sending request it not proceed further.No response generate. 
My app purchase type is entitlement and i am trying to test it on server.and i am not using amazon in app testing technique. For thisi also add my app on my amazon developer account.

Answer (score 2):

As documented by Amazon - if your app was not pushed through their App Store, it won't talk to the server.  You need to install the IAP SDK Tester and the associated data file for testing.